# UILabel word wrap preventing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uilabel

I have a label with about two lines of text, the problem is that the word is getting wrapped instead of getting smaller to fit the **fixed width** and **fixed height** !

[image]

Any idea on how to fix that programmatically will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just set the font to readjust its size according to the label width like so:

```
labelName.numberOfLines = 1;
labelName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: In In Swift 2 and Swift 1.2 you would want: `labelName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`

Comment: @Dan your answer is for `numberOfLines = 1` but I have two lines !!

Comment: @Dan haha That's will not fix the issue ... the characters will be wrapped again without changing the scale :(

Comment: @Husam Use a ```UITextView``` instead of a ```UILabel``` to fix this issue.

Comment: @Dan oooh good advice ... Will try then give you a feed back.